# UIButton disabled after animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have this button and apply this animation. 
The problem is that after the animation, the button seems to be disabled. 
The button is inside a UIView,  but its location is fixed, do not understand why it is disabled.

```
CABasicAnimation *alphaAnimation;

alphaAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnimation.duration=0.5;
alphaAnimation.repeatCount=1;
alphaAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
alphaAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
alphaAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

CAKeyframeAnimation *pulseAnimation;
pulseAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
pulseAnimation.duration = 0.5;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
pulseAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
pulseAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

pulseAnimation.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn],        // from keyframe 1 to keyframe 2
                                  [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut], nil]; // from keyframe 2 to keyframe 3

pulseAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pulseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

CAAnimationGroup *nearbyAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[nearbyAnimation setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pulseAnimation, alphaAnimation, nil]];
[nearbyAnimation setDuration:0.5];
[nearbyAnimation setBeginTime:0.0];
[nearbyAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[nearbyAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[nearbyButton.layer addAnimation:nearbyAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't the animation removed on completion?

Comment: Set removeOnCompletion to YES and see, it should surely work. Since you have the animation to the layer attached and it is not removed, your button do not work.

Comment: if I set YES, the button disappears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make UI object responsive after CABasicAnimation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159500/how-to-make-ui-object-responsive-after-cabasicanimation)