# Segmented control stops working after I animate it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got the segmented control to work, however when I move it, it gives me the weirdest bug. I can only click once and then stops working.

Here is my animation code, the one that is messing up the segmented control

```
- (void)moveUnitsUp:(UIView*) element {

    // Create an animation that will change the position of a layer
    CABasicAnimation *mover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [mover setDuration:0.12];
    [mover setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+0];

    // Setting starting position
    CGPoint initialPoint = [element.layer position];
    [mover setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:initialPoint]];

    // Setting ending position
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y - 50);
    [mover setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: finalPoint]];

    // MAKE SURE IT DOESN'T MOVE BACK TO STARTING POSITION
    [mover setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [mover setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

    // Add it to the layer
    [element.layer addAnimation:mover forKey:@"BigMove"];

    // SET THE POSITION TO THE STARTING POSITION
    [element.layer setPosition:finalPoint];

}
```

Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: Is the control a subview of the controller's self.view, or is it a subview of some other view? Why are you using this method rather than the UIView method, animateWithDuration:animations, which would require a lot less code?

Comment: I think it is a subview, I added it in the storyboard. Let me try that, however I still want to know why this doesnt work :-S

Comment: If a control moves outside the bounds of its superview, it won't respond to touches. If it's in a subview, give that subview a background color so you can see if the control is outside (or partially outside) of it.

Comment: @user3726682 I can't figure out why your segmented control stops working. I assume by "stop working" you mean it does not receive touch events anymore?

But here is a little tip: Never ever use those lines when animating properties, unless you know what you are doing.  
`// MAKE SURE IT DOESN'T MOVE BACK TO STARTING POSITION  
[mover setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];  
[mover setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];  `

Please look [here][1] for a good explanation and helpful links.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21160476/1688105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "mover" is only moving the .layer as opposed to the actual segmented bar. The layer is the just the presentation of the controller, the actual controller is still in the place where it started. To fix this, you'll want to also transform the actual controller to the new position at the end of your animation.

something like:

```
element.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-50);
```